# Setting ErrorHandler on XML Validator causes incorrect validation

Tags: java, xml, xsd, sax, xerces

I've run into what seems like some very strange behavior while using Java's XML `Validator` (which I believe uses the Apache Xerces implementation).

I'm trying to validate some XML documents against an XSD, and I want to log anything that causes a document to be invalid. I figured implementing my own `ErrorHandler` would allow me to do this. I quickly discovered that this caused XML documents to be erroneously validated (i.e. invalid XML was being identified as valid for my XSD).

I did some testing and found that simply setting the `Validator`'s `ErrorHandler` to anything was causing this behavior, illustrated below.

```
validator.validate(invalidXmlSource); // XML correctly identified as INVALID

validator.setErrorHandler(new DefaultHandler());
validator.validate(invalidXmlSource); // XML incorrectly identified as VALID
```

I would presume that the `Validator` uses `DefaultHandler` when one isn't specified, so I don't understand why the behavior is changing.

What is going on here?

**Edit**

```
public void validate(File dir, String xsdPath) {
    File schemaFile = new File(xsdPath);
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    //validator.setErrorHandler(new DefaultHandler()); <-- this line causes incorrect validation
    for (File xmlFile: dir.listFiles()) {
        try {
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(xmlFile));
            System.out.println("File '" + xmlFile.getName() + "' is valid.");
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("File '" + xmlFile.getName() + "' is NOT valid.");
            System.out.println("Reason: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Validator ofcourse incorrect. Try your own validator.

Comment: I think that the problem is with your custom ErrorHandler instead; I am also sure that your assumption vis-a-vis the use of the DefaultHandler has a twist (either is not true, or not properly configured). If you could show the code snippet which deals with errors (are you rethrowing?) it'll be easier to help.

Comment: I'm not even using my own `ErrorHandler` implementation at this point. I'm just setting the validator's handler to a `DefaultHandler` as described above and observing this behavior. I've added my validation code to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DefaultHandler` will do nothing for `error` and `warning`. It will, however, throw an exception for `fatalError`. Between the docs for `Validator` and `DefaultHandler`, you'll see that, for better or worse, you're getting exactly what you asked for. :)

Edit: Probably the main thing to note in the `Validator` docs is that the default (null) error handler will throw an exception for `error`...

Edit2: Here's an outline of a possible error handler to do what you want:

```
import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class LoggingErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    private boolean isValid = true;

    public boolean isValid() {
        return this.isValid;
    }

    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException exc) {
        // log info
        // valid or not?
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException exc) {
        // log info
        this.isValid = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException exc) throws SAXParseException {
        // log info
        this.isValid = false;
        throw exc;
    }
}
```

And it could used like so:

```
LoggingErrorHandler errorHandler = new LoggingErrorHandler();
validator.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
validator.validate(invalidXmlSource);
if (!errorHandler.isValid()) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so essentially `Validator` relies on a `SAXException` being thrown by the `ErrorHandler` to determine if a document is invalid. Since `DefaultHandler` does not throw any exceptions, `Validator` will not throw any `SAXException` if it's using one, regardless of the document passed to it.

Comment: In case you want to process the validation errors, you may want to gather them in a list.